# Firebase query doesn't get documents with a specific field

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running a query to get all documents from firebase containing a field of `location` contains, say 'Nairobi'. The structure of my database is `/posts/[userId]/userPosts/[postId]`. [image]
Now, when I specify the `userId` in my code, I get the documents.

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts')
          .doc("1092987983578079255")
          .collection('userPosts')
          .where('location', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '${placemark.locality}')
          .get();

      setState(() {
        posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
        isLoading = false;
      });
```

However, when I try to get all the documents within the entire `posts` collection, I get null results.

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts')
          .where('location', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '${placemark.locality}')
          .get();

      setState(() {
        posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
       
      });
```

I have tried using the code

```
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collectionGroup("userPosts")
          .where('location', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: '${placemark.locality}')
          .get();

      setState(() {
        posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
        isLoading = false;
      });
```

but I get the error `Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.`
given that, it is only querying through one criterion, I don't believe that a composite index is necessary but I, still, have created one.[image]
`adb logcat` doesn't give me the link to create an index even if I wrap the code in `try` to catch the error `e`.
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your Firestore structure?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have updated it in the question.

Comment: The second query `await postsRef.where('location', ...)` requires you to have `location` field in the documents of `posts` collection. Do you have that?

Comment: No, the `location` field is contained in the "great-grandchild" document of  `posts`

Comment: @Dharmaraj It is contained in the document `postId`

Comment: Then it's not going to work. Using the `.where` on posts collection will look for documents in posts collection only and not in any sub collection. Are you trying to find documents with that location in all the subcollections of all the posts? Then you should use CollectionGroups

Comment: I have tried using `collectionGroup` in my third query and face the issues I have described.

Comment: The collection name in collectionGroup should be that name of that sub collection. Please try `.collectionGroup("userPosts")`

Comment: I have changed that and even updated it in the index but I still get the same error `Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console`

Comment: You can try to [delete the index](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#:~:text=Field%20Indexes%20section.-,Go%20to%20the%20Single%20Field%20Indexes%20section,-In%20the%20list) you created and run the function again. When it throws an error, check the logs again by executing `adb logcat` and you should see a message like `'FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: <URL>`. Then use the link to fix the error